# Vimscript: how can I call a function but wait for user input before executing it?

Tags: vimscript

In the right-hand-side of a keymapping, you can do something like `:call FileTypeToggle("")<Left><Left>` to start a function call at the command line, move the cursor in between the quotes, and wait for the user to fill in the argument and hit `<CR>` manually.

How can you do the same from within a function? I've tried a bunch of permutations of `execute`, `call`, `normal`, and nothing seems to work. I either get errors about trailing characters (`<Left><Left>`) or it executes the function without waiting for user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the input() function.

```
let cmd = input("", "call FileTypeToggle(\"\")\<left>\<left>")
exe cmd
```

Comment: Not only did this answer my question, but it inspired me to redesign the function. Thanks!